# My app crashes while switching fast between 2 fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

need help.
I have two fragments that crashes my app while switching between them fast.

On main activity i have 2 buttons: lights button and garages button.
In addition , main activity contain container for both fragments that appear and disappear on click the 2 buttons (Lights , Garages).

While i switching between them fast, the app crashes with log: see below the code.

My code:
Part of the xml that contain container for the fragments list:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/garagesListCount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/top_border"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="30dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/garage_near"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/mainTextColor"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:translationZ="5dp" />

 //This is the container
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/garageListContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

GaragesFragment that contain Map fragment container and garages list fragment container:

```
public class GarageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_garage, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        showMap();
        }
    public void showMap() {
        if (getFragmentManager() != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, new MapsFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

GarageListFragment - App crashes on create this fragment:

```
public class GarageListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRVGarage;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private Garage mGarage;
    private ArrayList<Garage.GarageObject> mGarageObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    private GaragesAdapter mAdapter;
    private TextView mGarageCount;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_garage_list, container, false);
        readData();
        mRVGarage = view.findViewById(R.id.RVGarage);
        mAdapter = new GaragesAdapter(getActivity(), mGarageObjects);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRVGarage.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRVGarage.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnPhoneNumberClickListener(new GaragesAdapter.OnPhoneNumberClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPhoneNumberClick(int position, String phone) {
                dialGarage(phone);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void readData() {
        String json_string;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getAssets().open(getString(R.string.garage_json));
            int size = inputStream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();

            json_string = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            mGarage = gson.fromJson(json_string, Garage.class);


            for (int i = 0; i < 13273; i++) {
                if (mGarage.getGarage().get(i).garageCity.equals(AddressSingleton.getInstance().getmCurrentAddress())) {
                    if (!mGarageObjects.contains(mGarage.getGarage().get(i))) {
                        mGarageObjects.add(mGarage.getGarage().get(i));
//                        Log.d("AfterEdit", "readData: " + mGarageObjects.get(i).garageName);
                    }
                }
            }
            setGaragesCount();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Set garages count on garage fragment
    public void setGaragesCount() {
        fragment = Objects.requireNonNull(getFragmentManager()).findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment_container);
        if (fragment != null) {
            mGarageCount = Objects.requireNonNull(fragment.getView()).findViewById(R.id.garagesListCount);
        }
        mGarageCount.setText(String.valueOf(mGarageObjects.size()));
        mGarageCount.setText("נמצאו " + mGarageObjects.size() + " מוסכים בסביבתך! ");
    }

    private void dialGarage(String phone) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Maps fragment that initialise GarageListFragment onMapCreated:

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GarageListFragment mGarageListFragment;
    private LocationFinder mLocationFinder;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
        mLocationFinder = new LocationFinder(getContext());
        mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mMapFragment == null) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.map, mMapFragment).commit();
        }
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLocationFinder.getLatitude(), mLocationFinder.getLongitude()), 13));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(mLocationFinder.getLatitude(), mLocationFinder.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                .zoom(15)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        try {
            showGaragesListFragment();
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException i){
            i.getMessage();
        }
    }

    //Garage list will be shown after map is ready.
    public void showGaragesListFragment() {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.garageListContainer, new GarageListFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

Log from logcat:

```
2019-12-04 17:57:06.699 17732-17732/com.enjoyapp.carhelper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.enjoyapp.carhelper, PID: 17732
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900c3 (com.enjoyapp.carhelper:id/garageListContainer) for fragment GarageListFragment{b60bce6 (0722be3d-2c02-4e2b-aae1-4562ad068ba4) id=0x7f0900c3}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

[image]

Comment: If `GarageListFragment` is nested inside `GarageFragment`, you should be using `GarageListFragment`'s `getChildFragmentManager()` to transact it, not `getFragmentManager()`, which is the `Activity`'s `FragmentManager`.

Comment: Hi @MikeM. , I tried to do what you said, the app is still crashing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem same occurred to me, But I find the reason for this crash and searching for a solution.

This occurs because, when we switch fragments faster with a button call and using animation for the fragment transition, The fragment pop will be successful only after the completion of the animation-delay. So, When we click at the same time of animation, the fragment manager actually poping the root element or sometimes null.

Finally, I got a solution.

check if(!fragment.isRemoving()) before removing/replacing.